# If two graphs have similarity equal to 1 are their vertexes and edges equal?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, similarities, graph-theory

The similarity between two undirected graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ that have the same $n$ vertices can be defined using:

$$
S(G_1,G_2) =
\frac
{\sum_i\min(\deg(v_i \in G_1), \deg(v_i \in G_2))}
{2 \times \max(|G_1|,|G_2|)}
$$

where $\deg(v \in G)$ indicates the degree of a vertex $v$ in graph $G$ and $|G|$ indicates the number of edges in $G$.
If $S(G_1, G_2) = 1$, are the two graphs equivalent?

Comment: Is there some standard metric for similarity you are referring to? Can you provide a definition and/or reference?

Comment: Similarity of two undirected graphs having the same n vertices is 1

Comment: If that is the definition, then you would seem to have answered your own question? However your statement seems like an odd definition of *graph* similarity, when it only has to do with *vertex sets*. Typically a graph would be defined as $\{E,V\}$, which includes both a vertex set $V$ as well as an edge-set $E\subset V\times V$ (at a minimum, i.e. for an unweighted graph).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, **graph isomorphism is a harder problem then just matching vertex degrees,** as this figure demonstrates.

[image: Figure]

Both are undirected graphs on the same six vertices, labeled "1" through "6".  The vertex degrees on both are the same, vertex by vertex: one vertex ("1") has degree 5, two ("3" and "6") have degree 2, and three have degree 3.  Therefore **your similarity metric equals $1$.**

Note, however, that the three degree-3 vertices (labeled "2", "4", and "5") form a triangle at the left but not at the right.  Therefore **the two graphs are not isomorphic.**